# Equal to "=" characters randomy appearing in html POST data

Tags: html, http, post, django-views, http-post

I am posting HTML data from an input text field called "textbox" to a backend application. The backend application (a django view) receives the data bu it is garbled with random equal to "=" characters in between, even though the html content in "textbox" before posting, was perfectly fine.

I suspect this is a problem with the encoding of POST data, but I am not able to figure out a solution to avoid this.

The textbox data can have any html data, and special characters like  <, >, {, }.

To summarize the problem:

The text data like:

```
<p>This is a <b>sample</b> text<p>
<p> This is the second line </p>
```

becomes something like when I check the request.POST["textbox"] value in the Django view.

```
<p>Th=is is a <b>sample</b> tex=t<p>
<p> This i=s the se=cond line </p>
```

Is anyone facing a similar problem because I did not find any related questions on stackoverflow? AFAIK, I think this problem might not have specificity to Django, but still adding the information, in case its useful.

Comment: Can you post an example of the source generated of the form? Probably there is the issue.

Comment: @Niels: I am not sure if I got what you meant. Do you mean the structure of the html form?

Its something like this:
http://dpaste.com/hold/1544025/

It also has other fields including a file field, which I have omitted for brevity.

Comment: Also, I should also mention that I am using Django (Python), and I am checking the POST data using request.POST.get("textbox")
AFAIK, the problem is with the POST data encoding so the framework and language might not matter. But can't say for sure.